# Bash Script, Automated no and yes

Tags: bash, scripts

I need to have a script that instructs the system to run an fsck on a drive but I only want it to run if the drive is not mounted **"/dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt/Share ext4 defaults 0 2"**

Basically is it possible to either

1. tell it to run **"fsck /dev/mmcblk0p2 yes Y | command-that-asks-for-input"** after the attempted mount fails

Or

2. Tell it to run **"fsck /dev/mmcblk0p2 (no to first question then) yes Y | command-that-asks-for-input"**

Thanks so much oh great and powerful men behind the curtains. May the force be with you.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `mount` command to check if the drive is mounted. Use `grep` to check if the output includes the desired partition/drive. Use the `||` operator to run your command if the partition is not mounted.

`mount | grep /dev/mmcblk0p2 > /dev/null || fsck/dev/mmcblk0p2 ...`

Comment: I think you'll find that you need sudo to run fsck `Permission denied while trying to open /dev/sda1
You must have r/w access to the filesystem or be root`